# Graphics.TBitmap successfully decoded from a JPEG frame results in empty TDibSection after GetObject() call

Tags: delphi, graphics, bitmap, jpeg

I am decoding JPEG frames to Graphics.TBitmap objects using the FastJpeg library (jpegdec.pas).  The decode works fine and I print the bitmap to file for visual inspection using the TBitmap.SaveToFile() method and it looks great.  I then call GetObject() using the TBitmap handle to get a TDibSection object.  The TDibSection object returned does show the correct values for the top level fields (bmWidth, bmHeight, etc.) although bmBit is NIL and I find that surprising seeing as the SaveToFile() call did write the image out to disk correctly.  The problem I'm having is that the TBitmapHeaderInfo field (dsBmih) is all zeroes.  Also, the dsBitFields, dshSection, and dsOffset fields are all zeroes too if that matters.  It's as if it filled in the primary fields and everything after that was left out.  Here's a dump of the TDibSection object returned:

```
dsBm: (0, 320, 240, 1280, 1, 32, nil)
dsBmih: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
dsBitfields: (0, 0, 0)
dshSection: 0
dsOffset: 0
```

The code below shows bascially what I am doing.  Why am I getting back a blank TBitmapHeaderInfo field?  This is causing problems with my calls to the AVI dll so I need to fix this.

Here's the code snippet

```
var
    theBitmap: Graphics.TBitmap;
    aryBytes: TDynamicByteArray;
    dibs: TDibSection;
begin
    aryBytes := nil;

    // The following function loads JPEG frame #0 from a collection of JPEG frames.
    aryBytes := LoadJpegFrame(0);

    // Decode the first JPEG frame so we can pass it to the compressor
    //  selector call.
    theBitmap := JpegDecode(@aryBytes[0], Length(aryBytes));

    if GetObject(theBitmap.Handle, sizeof(dibs), @dibs) = 0 then
        raise Exception.Create('Get Object failed getting the TDibSection information for the bitmap.');

    // ... The TBitmapHeaderInfo field in dibs is empty as described in the post.
end;
```

UPDATE: In response to the comment by TLama I have updated the code as you can see below.  It now works.  I have some questions:

1) Can the code be streamlined?  It is obviously a lot more complicated than the original code above and perhaps I am performing too many steps.

2) Am I freeing all the memory and releasing all the GDI handles & objects that I need to?  I don't want any memory leaks.

Here is the updated code:

```
var
    hr: HRESULT;
    bmi: TBitmapInfo;
    pImg: PJpegDecode;
    jpegDecodeErr: TJpegDecodeError;
    hbm: HBITMAP;
    pBits: Pointer;
begin
    hr := 0; pImg := nil; hbm := 0; pBits := nil;

    try
        jpegDecodeErr := JpegDecode(@aryBytes[0], Length(aryBytes), pImg);

        if jpegDecodeErr <> JPEG_SUCCESS then
            raise Exception.Create('(TfrmMain_moviemaker_.cmdTestClick) The bitmap failed to decode with error code: ' + IntToStr(Ord(jpegDecodeErr)));

        if not Assigned(pImg) then
            raise Exception.Create('(TfrmMain_moviemaker_.cmdTestClick) The bitmap decoded from the first JPEG frame in the video file is unassigned: ' + fullVideoInFilename);

        pImg^.ToBMI(bmi);

        theBitmap := pImg.ToBitmap;

        // Now create a DIB section.
        hbm := CreateDIBSection(theBitmap.Handle, bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, pBits, 0, 0);

        if hbm = ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER then
            raise Exception.Create('(TfrmMain_moviemaker_.cmdTestClick) One of the parameters passed to CreateDIBSection is invalid.');

        if hbm = 0 then
            raise Exception.Create('(TfrmMain_moviemaker_.cmdTestClick) The call to CreateDIBSection failed.');

        // Select the compressor.  This call USED to fail before TLama's
        //  suggestion.  Now it works.
        hr := aviMaker.compression(hbm, nil, true, Self.Handle);

        if hr <> S_OK then
            raise Exception.Create('(TfrmMain_moviemaker_.cmdTestClick) Error during compressor selector call: ' + FormatAviMessage(hr));
    finally
        if Assigned(pImg) then
        begin
            pImg^.Free;
            pImg := nil;
        end;

        if Assigned(theBitmap) then
            FreeAndNil(theBitmap);

        if hbm > 0 then
            DeleteObject(hbm);
    end; // try (2)
end;
```

Comment: If we are talking about the Synopse's [`JPEG decoder`](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/03/18/Fast-JPEG-decoder-using-SSE/SSE2-version-1.1), the call *stack* is as following `JpegDecode -> TJpegDecode.ToBitmap -> TJpegDecode.ToBMI`, where the header is being filled. However I think the [`GetObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) requires the handle of the image created by the `CreateDIBSection` function, so I would try to call it inside of the `TJpegDecode.ToBMI`. But anyway what information do you need to get ?

Comment: @TLama - Thank you, that worked, see my updated post in the section titled UPDATE.  I'd like to accept your comment as an answer if you'd like to rewrite as such.

Comment: 1) might be; it depends mainly on when you actually need a `TBitmap` for your AVI compressor (e.g. for the `AviMaker.Compression` function) or for something else or if the handle to the device independent bitmap (DIB) representation of the frame will be enough for you 2) seems to be ok, but I'll take a look closer!

Comment: @TLama.  Thanks.  I am having another problem however.  The bits returned in pBits are all zero despite the bitmap having valid image data.  I know this because if I use TBitmap.SaveToFile() I see a complete image.  However, looking at the memory area pointed to pBits^ after the CreateDIBSection() call shows nothing but zeroes and the AVI file that is output is all "black" frames.  Do you know what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: You would need to call the `GetDIBits` subsequently, but since it seems you don't need a `TBitmap`... Before I'll try to answer, what should be passed to the `AviMaker.Compression`, is that a handle to the DIB ?

Comment: @TLama - It's a handle to the DIB section.  The Compression call internally does calls GetObject(bmp, sizeof(dibs), @dibs) where "bmp" is an HGDIOBJ and "dibs" is a TDibSection. "bmp" is the result of a CreateDIBSection(theBitmap.Handle, bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, pBits, 0, 0) call.  Note I have source to the Compression() call if there is a more streamlined and faster way (computationally) to do this.  The Compression() call ends up making a call to AVIStreamSetFormat(FAvi_.thePsCompressed, 0, (at)dibs.dsBmih, dibs.dsBmih.biSize+dibs.dsBmih.biClrUsed * sizeof(RGBQUAD)).  The point of all this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need only a handle to the DIB section of the first frame decoded from the JPEG file, I think it should be enough to use the [`CreateDIBSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183494%28VS.85%29.aspx) and copy to the block of memory allocated by the function call the content pointed by the `TJpegDecode.pRGB`, which should be the DIB section values already.

```
procedure ProbeGetObject(ACanvas: TCanvas; AGDIObject: HGDIOBJ);
var
  Width, Height: Integer;
  DIBSection: TDIBSection;
  BitmapInfo: TBitmapInfo;
begin
  if GetObject(AGDIObject, SizeOf(DIBSection), @DIBSection) <> 0 then
  begin
    FillChar(BitmapInfo, SizeOf(BitmapInfo), 0);
    BitmapInfo.bmiHeader := DIBSection.dsBmih;
    // if you comment the following line, the image will be rendered flipped
    BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight := - BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight;
    Width := DIBSection.dsBm.bmWidth;
    Height := Abs(DIBSection.dsBm.bmHeight);
    StretchDIBits(ACanvas.Handle, 0, 0, Width, Height, 0, 0, Width, Height,
      DIBSection.dsBm.bmBits, BitmapInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY);
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeCompressor(Buffer: Pointer; BufferLen: Integer);
var
  ScreenDC: HDC;
  DIBHandle: HBITMAP;
  DIBValues: Pointer;
  BufferSize: DWORD;
  BufferHandle: THandle;
  BufferPointer: Pointer;
  JPEGImage: PJpegDecode;
  BitmapInfo: TBitmapInfo;
begin
  if JpegDecode(Buffer, BufferLen, JPEGImage) = JPEG_SUCCESS then
  try
    JPEGImage^.ToBMI(BitmapInfo);
    BufferSize := Abs(BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth *
      BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight * 4);
    BufferHandle := CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, nil,
      PAGE_READWRITE, 0, BufferSize, nil);
    if BufferHandle <> 0 then
    try
      BufferPointer := MapViewOfFile(BufferHandle, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 0);
      if Assigned(BufferPointer) then
      begin
        CopyMemory(BufferPointer, JPEGImage^.pRGB, BufferSize);
        ScreenDC := GetDC(0);
        if ScreenDC <> 0 then
        try
          DIBHandle := CreateDIBSection(ScreenDC, BitmapInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS,
            DIBValues, BufferHandle, 0);
          if (DIBHandle <> 0) and Assigned(DIBValues) then
          try
            ProbeGetObject(Form1.Canvas, DIBHandle);
            // here try to initialize the compressor, the DIB section should
            // contain values obtained from the JPEG decoder; in the DIBHandle
            // variable is the handle to the DIB section
          finally
            DeleteObject(DIBHandle);
          end;
        finally
          ReleaseDC(0, ScreenDC);
        end;
      end;
    finally
      CloseHandle(BufferHandle);
    end;
  finally
    JPEGImage^.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Try it now; it's [`more complicated`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/01/08/9945482.aspx) because of the requirement for `CreateDIBSection` and `GetObject`. You simply cannot create DIB section and then get it back by a `GetObject` call, you have to use memory mapped files instead. Now the `GetObject` should work properly.

Comment: Thanks, that worked as far as getting the bits to show up in the buffer.  Faster too since it's direct access to the bits.  I still have work to do because the AVI file being output has problems.  I'm starting to wonder if the sample I'm working from is valid or perhaps I did something wrong when I converted it from C++.  It's gone from being all black to having some kind of format problem that video players can't handle.  But that's another problem.  Also, what should I do if ScreenDC = 0?  What does that mean and what kind of error should I throw because of it?

Comment: I was wrong.  Windows Media Player can play it, although it's upside down.  Guess I need to flip the image vertically.  However VLC Player shows all black.  I'll start another question for that.  But a big thanks for you your help.  You really went the extra mile.  Unfortunately I can only give you one vote because SO only allows me 1.

Comment: Can you think of a quick way to flip the bits vertically without having to resort to something like BitBlt() or StretchBlt()?  Perhaps a clever change in the copy operation?  The code is really nice and fast now and I don't want to unwind that.

Comment: The problem with the image flip is caused by the `GetObject`; the header lose its negative `biHeight` value (hard to say why, but take a look on testing function added to my post). I'm starting to think about overloading functions operating with the DIBs. You would leave all the stuff with mapped file and creating DIB section at all, you would just pass the pointer to pixel values and bitmap header separately. Could you post a link to the component you are using for AVI processing (there's a lot of them). About the error message when `GetDC(0)` fails, it might be `you're in a big trouble` :-)

Comment: Here's the Delphi AVI writer unit I ported from a C++ code sample: http://www.robodance.com/AviWriterWithCompression.pas.  Look at the code block immediately after the unit "end." statement to see the code from another unit that calls this unit to add video frames.  If you see anything that would affect compression from being applied correctly please let me know.  When I choose a Compressor from the available DirectShow compressors, I still get an AVI output file containing uncompressed frames.  I say this because the output file is the same size as if I chose "uncompressed frames".